Unexpected additional output in transaction
https://explorer.btc.com/btc/transaction/c5069dd52612dd07cfff6a2c587356497a2f8e7489923376a92420850fe27d09
I only did an 0.01 transfer to freebitco.in but somehow it puts an additional 0.027 BTC transfer to an unintended address in there. How can I cancel it, please help fast, I don't understand why this is happening.
I was able to cancel the before this transaction 0.01 with my core, but seems to have no impact to these 0.037 transaction(0.01+0.027), I even am trying to send the remaining from my core wallet to the same intended address, but the option to cancel the faulty transfer is yet not being shown.
v25.0.0 bitcoin-core.exe

Are you sure the filename is bitcoin-core.exe and not bitcoin-qt.exe?

See also Is bitcoin.org or bitcoincore.org the one to trust? bitcoin.org seems to be providing v25 but the latest version at bitcoincore.org is v27.
